# Java Regular Expression processing

Tags: java, regex

if I have a text

> **R 26** bla bla bla bla **R 25** bla bla **R
>   25/30** bla bla bla **S 30/50/30** bla bla

and I have a regex

```
[RS] (\\d+|\\d+/\\d+|\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)
```

which will match the bold data ...
now , I want a code that returns for me the bold expressions + the following data.

For example , I want the following pairs:

```
R 26 : bla bla bla bla
R 25 : bla bla
R 25/30 : bla bla bla
S 30/50/30 : bla bla
```

may be this image will be clearer :

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMerw.png

Comment: " I want a code " - is that a 'plz sendz the codez' variant?

Comment: See [this meta faq answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19780#19780)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go!

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([RS] (\\d+|\\d+/\\d+|\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)) ([^RS]*)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("R 26 bla bla bla bla R 25 bla bla R 25/30 bla bla bla S 30/50/30 bla bla");

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Comment: This implements the Java code but the regex is the same as the original which does not work.

Comment: @ridgerunner - I only paste code once I verify that they work. The orignal RegEx had an escaping issue. This one is different.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the alternatives is important. With your original regex, the second and third alternatives will never match. Reversing their order fixes the problem like so:

```java
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([RS] (\\d+/\\d+/\\d+|\\d+/\\d+|\\d+)) ([^RS]*)");
```